# Generate quote on Products by Year/Length

Tags: opportunity-lineitem, quote, quotelineitem, quote-template

I am trying to have Many quotes on 1 Opportunity however, use case is:

1 Opportunity can have the same product quoted for 1 year, 2 years, 3 years.
I want to add this product and show the 3 different prices on one quote.

However, right now, the sales team would need to either generate, x3 opportunites - which is incorrect for forecasting.
OR add all the products (License 1 year, License 2 years etc - as these have different list prices) then generate a quote, however, this would not
1) split our the length  of licenses; 1 or 2 or 3 years 
2) it would also total all of the line items which is not what i want.

I would ideally like to select which product line item to include in a particular section and quote.

Any help massively appreciated!

Thank you
Jin

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few ways to do it

option 1
Create blanket opportunity. Create 3 quotes against this opp, one for each year. Depending on which option users go with, change the status to "approved" and sync the quote back to opportunity. You can delete other quote, or keep them as-is

option 2
Create blanket opportunity. Create 1 quote showing products for all 3 years. Customer can confirm one of the option. Depending on what the choose, you can delete other line items. Change the status to "approved" and sync the quote back to opportunity.

In either case, as there are no products on opportunity to begin with, it won't mess up forecasting

Standard PDF does not do good job of grouping products and showing aggregate for each group. If you are OK with 3rd party apps, there are many good apps that will send professional PDF and automate some of this process. Conga is one, other is [Quote PDF](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N3000000B4AsxEAF) which I have heard good things about.

All the best